# eJabberd cannot invite several users to multiple MUC room

Tags: ejabberd, multiuserchat

I have run this code:

**`sudo -u ejabberd /usr/sbin/ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation mt75_1 conference.msg.hajmobility.my none none msg_din@msg.hajmobility.my:msg_apool@msg.hajmobility.my`**

It works for the first time.

But when i want to add the same user into another MUC room using the same code its not working.

Comment: What is the error message? Do you have a better description of what is not working exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that problem in ejabberd 18.03

I create two rooms, then invite two users to them. One user is online and receives the invitations immediately and can join them. The other invited user is offline, when he logins, he receives both invitations and can join the rooms too.

```
$ ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation room1 conference.localhost none none user3@localhost:user4@localhost
$ ejabberdctl send_direct_invitation room2 conference.localhost none none user3@localhost:user4@localhost
```